# How can I URL Rewrite folders while serving static assets on nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm totally new to Nginx and I have trouble to set it up with my small PHP/Slim website.

My website maps URLs like:

`/`,
`/news`,
`/about`,
`/user/<user>`, and so on...

I almost managed to get this working with this:

```
server {
  ...

  location / {
     if (!-e $request_filename) {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php break; #app.php is my main PHP file
     }

     fastcgi_... #PHP-FPM things here...
  }

  ...
}
```

But, with the code above, I can't map `/` and my assets found in `/assets/css/style.css` do not load.

How can I get this working?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use separate location for static assets (text, pictures, audio, video, files, you can add more extensions if you need). And you need separate location for handle *.php, remove fastcgi configuration from / section. So you will have 3 locations (at least :) like this.

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /app.php?$args;
}

location ~* \.(txt|ico|css|js|bmp|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|swf|avi|mp4|webm|pdf|mel|rar|zip|bin)$ {
  expires max;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  # here can be more assets-optimized rules )
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  # minimal fastcgi configuration:
  if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php break; } # Catch 404s that try_files miss
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; # put your real backend here!
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Comment: With the code above, the browser keep loading. It must be being redirected between the locations definition endlessly.

Comment: Configuration in my example is correct, tested on localhost and based on my working nginx templates. Maybe something broken in full nginx configuration on your server. I also added minimal fastcgi parameters for php location.